# How can I get an element of a HashSet with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, hashset

I'm trying to get the type of an array elements. I got something like this:

```
Set<Foo> mySet = new HashSet<Foo>();
```

I have to take via reflection the 'Foo' as a String.
I tried something like this:

```
if (className.equals("java.util.HashSet")){
        Object arrayElement = Array.get(value, 0);
        isComplex = isComplex(field, arrayElement);
}
```

`Array.get()` is only for ArrayList and there isn't any `HashSet.iterator()`as Util

Thanks!

Comment: Ignore the line `isComplex = isComplex(field, arrayElement)`
Is just a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to obtain the Foo is:

```
ParameterizedType listType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
Class<?> stringListClass = (Class<?>) listType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

But you must be sure that `field` is an Array/Collection/HashSet, else, will be an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear, *but* in this code

```
new HashSet<Foo>();
```

you have **no** chance to get the `Foo` part via reflection. Period. The relevant search term is "type erasure".